# What is the best text analyzer to use on generic data in Azure Cognitive Search when searching for more than 1 word?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have been looking over the different text analyzers which Azure Cognitive Search offers  [with this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer).
The type of data I have is generic and can be either an email address / name, these are just some examples.

1. Which is the best analyzer to use on this type of data (generic)?

Also, does the text analyzer in use affect how search works when looking for more than 1 word?

- What is the best way to make it do a fuzzy search for more than 1 word i.e. "joe blogs" but all fuzzy.
- I don't want "somename blogs" to show up for somename is not a fuzzy match on joe.
- I do want "joe clogs" to show up for joe would fuzzy match to joe and clogs would fuzzy match on blogs.

2. What is the best practice to do fuzzy search with more than 1 word, which would give the end user fewer hits as they give more words?

Answer (score 0):

If you have generic content and don't want to use linguistic processing, you can use a generic analyzer like the Whitespace analyzer. See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#built-in-analyzers

How searches for single or multiple words work is determined by the **searchMode** parameter. The recommended practice is to use **all**, instead of **any**. When you specify more terms, you are more specific and you want fewer (more precise) results.

You can specify multi-word queries where individual search terms are fuzzy by using the tilde syntax. E.g. to do a fuzzy search for **joe** but exact match on blogs you could something like:

```
joe~ blogs
```

You can also control how fuzzy you want it to be. See

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_fuzzy

PS: From your use case it sounds like proximity matching is also something you could consider using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_proximity